# Match multiple characters without repetion on a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm using PHP's PCRE, and there is one bit of the regex I can't seem to do. I have a character class with 5 characters [adjxz] which can appear or not, in any order,  after a token (|) on the string. They all can appear, but they can only each appear once. So for example:

```
 *|ad     - is valid
 *|dxa    - is valid
 *|da     - is valid
 *|a      - is valid
 *|aaj    - is *not* valid
 *|adjxz  - is valid
 *|addjxz - is *not* valid
```

Any idea how I can do it? a simple `[adjxz]+`, or even `[adjxz]{1,5}`  do not work as they allow repetition. Since the order does not matter also, I can't do `/a?d?j?x?z?/`, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: This seems like overkill for regex... why not just iterate through each character and keep track of duplicates? After all, you only have to check for 5 unique characters.

Comment: It is part of a much longer regexp. Due the way the framework I'm on works, it would be better to do everything on the same preg_match call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using a lookahead combined with a backreference like this:

```
\|(?![adjxz]*([adjxz])[adjxz]*\1)[adjxz]{1,5}
```

[**demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%7C%28?!%5Badjxz%5D%2a%28%5Badjxz%5D%29%5Badjxz%5D%2a%5C1%29%5Badjxz%5D%7B1,5%7D&input=%2a%7Cad%20%20%20%20%20-%20is%20valid%0A%2a%7Cdxa%20%20%20%20-%20is%20valid%0A%2a%7Cda%20%20%20%20%20-%20is%20valid%0A%2a%7Ca%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20is%20valid%0A%2a%7Caaj%20%20%20%20-%20is%20%2anot%2a%20valid%0A%2a%7Cadjxz%20%20-%20is%20valid%0A%2a%7Caddjxz%20-%20is%20%2anot%2a%20valid)

If you know these characters are followed by something else, e.g. whitespace you can simplify this to:

```
\|(?!\S*(\S)\S*\1)[adjxz]{1,5}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should break this in 2 steps:

1. A regex to check for unexpected characters
2. A simple PHP check for duplicated characters

```php
function strIsValid($str) {
    if (!preg_match('/^\*|([adjxz]+)$/', $str, $matches)) {
        return false;
    }

    return strlen($matches[1]) === count(array_unique(str_split($matches[1])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using reverse logic where you match the unwanted case using this pattern
`\|.*?([adjxz])(?=.*\1)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cI9jS2)